# How to basic array data from Json array Response in angular js

Tags: angularjs

This is the my json Array response and I want to get basic array data from the below json resonse but not able to do it. Please help me.I am trying to get the array data in a JSON response. The following is my JSON response and I need to get basic object from the data array.

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "PartyObj":{
        "finaInfo":[
        ],
        "addInfo":[
            {"extraInfoId": "PEI-210", "notes": "cxcxz", "createdDate": "2018-03-09T11:34:10", "updatedDate": "2018-04-19T12:19:38",…}
        ],
        "contacts":[
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "Raju", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "Srivastva",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "ravish", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "Kumar",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "7004132370", "firstName": "ramesh", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "kumar",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "rakhi", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "ranjan",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "ravish", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "bhaiya",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "sakshi", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "sona",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "sakshi", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "sona",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "ravi", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "powar",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "poonam", "title": "Miss", "lastName": "Kumar",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "poonam", "title": "Miss", "lastName": "Kumar",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "Govind", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "sah",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "Rahul", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "Singh",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "7004132370", "firstName": "abjit", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "singh",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "krishna", "title": "Miss", "lastName": "po",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "roushan", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "ragav",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "Ramesh", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "jha",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "7004132370", "firstName": "ravi", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "raj",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "ravi", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "sastri",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "7004132370", "firstName": "rovin", "title": "Ms", "lastName": "singh",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9060274944", "firstName": "ravi", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "powar",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "raushan", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "kamti",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "raghu", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "yadav",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "rk", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "gupta",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "9066277103", "firstName": "akhilesh", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "yadav",…},
            {"mobileNumber": "7004132370", "firstName": "Roushan", "title": "Mr", "lastName": "sah",…}
        ],
        "trustedInfo":[
            {"mobilenumber": "", "updatedBy": null, "gstnumber": "123456789987456", "verified": false,…}
        ],
        // I want this object Data
        "basic":{
            "city": "1087",
            "createdDate": "2018-02-13T21:00:19",
            "cityid": 1087,
            "latitude": "16.7049873",
            "partyCategory": "CUSTCAT-2",
            "updatedBy": null,
            "partyName": " Jindal steel",
            "updatedDate": "2018-04-19T11:53:44",
            "longitude": "74.2432527",
            "isApproved": false,
            "postalCode": "416003",
            "state": "506",
            "partyId": "PAR-309",
            "createdBy": null,
            "addressLine1": "Kolhapur",
            "aboutcompany": "Testing purpose",
            "addressLine2": "",
            "stateid": 506,
            "country": "100",
            "partyType": "supplier",
            "isActive": true
        }
    },
    "responsecode": 200
}
```

Comment: you can simply use dot notation to get the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your basic object is inside party object therefore you can try the following to get basic object

```
{{data.PartyObj.basic}}
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ny0Xw8La0oDEForipC7Z?p=preview)**